# Case sensitive data causing error in SSAS cube processing

Tags: ssas

I have a dimension attribute value as "Us" and "US".
While processing the dimension the SSAS is giving duplicate key error as both the values do not have the same cases.
However in the SQL database this does not seem to be an issue.
Please help me understand why this actually happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your SQL database (or at least that column) uses a case sensitive collation but SSAS uses a case insensitive collation. Can you change both to the same collation? The problem is that a SELECT DISTINCT query in SQL returns a list which isn't distinct according to SSAS and its collation.

Comment: The database is Netezza in this case.

Comment: @surya, if you can't change the collation to case insensitive in Netezza (or actually edit the data to have similar casing), then you may want to change the collation to case sensitive in SSAS. If you open your solution in Visual Studio and right click in Solution Explorer on the database node and choose Edit Database then look in the Properties pane you will see a Collation property you can change.